# Moving average: Compute AVG with Last N data continuosly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, moving-average

I have a table like this:

```
Name       Poin
================
ANA         5
ANA         10
ANA         3
ANA         8
ANA         7
ANA         5
```

I want to get AVG for last 2 rows continuosly like this:

```
Name       Poin    AVG 2
=========================
ANA         5       7.5
ANA         10      6.5 
ANA         3       5.5
ANA         8       7.5
ANA         7        6
ANA         5        5
```

The "AVG 2" column is average between a row and row -1. How can I do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Row-1 can not be defined for the table in question as it has nor ordering key. Sql table is unodered set of rows by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [windowing function with `OVER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql)

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Id int, Name nvarchar(10), Poin float)

INSERT INTO @table 
VALUES
(1, N'ANA',5),
(2, N'ANA',10),
(3, N'ANA',3),
(4, N'ANA',8),
(5, N'ANA',7),
(6, N'ANA',5);

SELECT AVG(Poin) OVER(PARTITION BY Name 
                      ORDER BY Id 
                      ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING)
FROM @table;
```

The result

```
7,5
6,5
5,5
7,5
6
5
```

**Important**:

Please be aware, that there is **no implicit order** within your table. Without a specific `ORDER BY` the result is random!

Comment: I like your solution :)

Comment: Thanks, this is a best answer. Can I change code "1 FOLLOWING", so it can be more dynamic less than just 1 row?

Comment: @TommySayugo Regrettfully the number must be an *unsigned integer literal*. You might create this statement on string level and execute it dynamically with `EXEC`, but this has quite some back draws too...

Answer (score 0):

With [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) function you can get next row ordered by Id:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Id int, Name nvarchar(10), Poin float)

INSERT INTO @table 
VALUES
(1, N'ANA',5),
(2, N'ANA',10),
(3, N'ANA',3),
(4, N'ANA',8),
(5, N'ANA',7),
(6, N'ANA',5)


SELECT
    t.Id,
    (t.Poin + LEAD(t.Poin, 1, t.Poin) OVER (ORDER BY t.Id)) / 2
FROM @table AS t
```

`LEAD(t.Poin, 1, t.Poin)`

- `LEAD` - get next Nth row
- `t.Poin` - column
- `1` - move forward on 1 row
- `t.Poin` - replacement for the last row, when there is no next value

Comment: That's good answer, instead divide by 2.00 will give decimals and cast as decimal (18,2)

Comment: @BHouse I have floats in table